# How to open a DatePicker onClick of an Edittext within a custom AlertDialog activity in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog, customdialog, datepickerdialog

I need to open to DatePicker from a custom created AlertDialog Activity for the purpose of setting 'From Date' and 'To Date'. The DatePicker is to be opened while onClick of the Edittext placed in the AlertDialog Activity. However I tried I cannot open the DatePicker. I will attach the code I have done.

In **RequestActivity.class**

```
const_leave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(RequestActivity.this);
                final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_leave_request, null);
                final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RequestActivity.this).create();

                deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
                deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_LeaveOk).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        deleteDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_LeaveCancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        deleteDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

The code for AlertDialog Activity i.e. **LeaveRequestActivity.class**

```
public class LeaveRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etFromDateValue, etToDate, etRemarkValue;
TextView tvtolabel, tvdaysvalue, tvdayslabel;
Button btn_LeaveCancel, btn_LeaveOk;
Spinner spin;

private DatePickerDialogFragment mDatePickerDialogFragment;

Calendar myCalendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_request);

    cast();

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    etFromDateValue.setOnClickListener(this);
    etToDate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void cast(){
    etFromDateValue= findViewById(R.id.etFromDateValue);
    etToDate= findViewById(R.id.etToDate);
    etRemarkValue= findViewById(R.id.etRemarkValue);
    tvtolabel = findViewById(R.id.tvtolabel);
    tvdaysvalue= findViewById(R.id.tvdaysvalue);
    tvdayslabel= findViewById(R.id.tvdayslabel);
    btn_LeaveCancel= findViewById(R.id.btn_LeaveCancel);
    btn_LeaveOk = findViewById(R.id.btn_LeaveOk);
    spin = findViewById(R.id.sp_leaveRequest);
    mDatePickerDialogFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.etFromDateValue) {
        mDatePickerDialogFragment.setFlag(DatePickerDialogFragment.FLAG_START_DATE);
        mDatePickerDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    } else if (id == R.id.etToDate) {
        mDatePickerDialogFragment.setFlag(DatePickerDialogFragment.FLAG_END_DATE);
        mDatePickerDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 0;
    public static final int FLAG_END_DATE = 1;

    private int flag = 0;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void setFlag(int i) {
        flag = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
            etFromDateValue.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
        } else if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
            etToDate.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Does anyone know on how to implement Datepicker on an AlertDialog activity please share your idea. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are your trying to create an activity for alert dialog. Dialog and activity are two different types of classes.

Comment: Well it worked in my case? Do you have any method?